# Couldn't connect to IBM MQ due to MQRC_UNSUPPORTED_CIPHER_SUITE

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, apache-camel, ibm-mq

I couldn't connect to IBM MQ
It throws following exception

```
org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager '' with connection mode 'Client' and host name ''. Check the queue manager is started and if running in client mode, check there is a listener running. Please see the linked exception for more information.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2400' ('MQRC_UNSUPPORTED_CIPHER_SUITE').
```

1. SSL is configured with certs using connection factory.
2. com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false
3. Java 11
4. Valid cipher suite has been set
5. Apache camel is also present in the lib
6. I tried in both ways using Camel routing and standard JMS.

Comment: Not sure the version of MQ you are using. But this page gives you a list of ciphers supported - https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=jms-tls-cipherspecs-ciphersuites-in-mq-classes. Compare the cipher you are using with the list.

Comment: First, you should make sure the code works without SSL/TLS.  Once you have successfully connected the application without SSL/TLS then add the SSL/TLS parameters to your application configuration.

Comment: You should also check if java 11 is supported with the version of MQ that the com.ibm.mq*.jar files are from.   I would suggest you provide the full version of both MQ and java and the cipher you are trying to use in the question (you can click edit to add more information).   This will help you to get and answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Identified the issue. The problem is incompatibility between IBM MQ client and server versions. I could connect it successfully after using latest version of mq-jms-spring-boot-starter:2.7.12